# How do I create a new non-live Skype account?

Tags: user-accounts, skype

Newly created Skype accounts nowadays usually prepend "live:" to the account name ("live:account") suggesting that they are really Microsoft accounts.

Now, while we all know that Skype accounts are "linked" to Microsoft accounts (*they* call them "linked"), the former don't appear to be just "linked" anymore but simply nonexistent with newly created "Skype accounts" and fully replaced by the Microsoft account.

*How do I create a new non-live Skype account?*

Comment: Skype is owned by microsoft, so yes. They are the same account. You cannot create an old style account because Microsoft wants to phase them out at some point/convert to the new format.

Comment: Could somebody provide some possible reasons why my question got downvoted? It may be something worth learning.

Comment: Its possible the downvoters missed the question in the title, similar as how @Seth missed it, or they misunderstood you, or they are just jerks. Usually when something is not clear, people downvote. In any case, for next time, the title is only a description on what the question is about, the question itself should be in the large text field, possibly at the very bottom.

Comment: I thought I did send the "Right. Thank you." message and I don't see it posted. Not sure what happened. I updated my question.

Comment: [This Microsoft answers post](https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/skype/forum/skype_accountms-skype_setupms/skype-account-mit-live-prefix-l%C3%B6schen/f93f74b5-064e-427a-b985-6c3d37b03e2a?auth=1) (german) would support what @LPChip said. It's not possible to create old-style accounts anymore and, according to the post, it shouldn't even be possible to login with them anymore.  The "live:" prefix might be related to having a login before the complete integration.

Comment: @Seth I would find an answer based on your comment fully acceptable. (I mean there's no reason for it to be just a comment.)

Comment: "How do I create a new non-live Skype account?" - You can't.  Skype transitioned to Microsoft Accounts over 3 years ago.  It is no longer possible to create a legacy Skype account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else that needs closure; Skype accounts have been phased out almost fully. There's a few remaining ones the users of which Microsoft hasn't *yet* managed to force to do the upgrade. They will be required to on their first website login.

On Ubuntu and alternatives this means you can't call or be called and lately can't even receive messages other than private, unless you use the new webapp-based Skype that is still pre-pre-alpha except for the name and stability. If you're lucky to have a Skype account, everything works just fine except with interlocutors that use the new Skype; "new" refers to both the above-mentioned and an Android one Microsoft've been trying to push since a few months ago.